# How can I adapt this Elm code from the guide to initialise with a random number?

Tags: elm

I am looking into Elm, and reading through [this guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/).

On the [example concerning random numbers](https://guide.elm-lang.org/effects/random.html):

It currently initialized the die value to 1, before any rolls have occurred.
I'd like to modify the code such that it initializes to a random value.

My incorrect attempt tries to modify the `init` function:

```
init : () -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init _ =
  ( Model 1
  , Task.perform (\_ -> Roll) never
  )
```

This does not work. Is trying to modify the `init` function the right approach? How else can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

I feel kinda silly now, but here is the obvious answer:

```
init : () -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init _ =
  ( Model 1
  , Random.generate NewFace (Random.int 1 6)
  )
```